# CMake error while using vcpkg and find_package() "configuration file was considered but not accepted"

Tags: c++, cmake, vcpkg

I'm trying to add the header-only library *frugally-deep* into my *CMake* project using vcpkg and the find*package()* command. I installed the frugally-deep package and its dependencies (Eigen3, nlohmannjson and FunctionalPlus) beforehand with the `vcpkg install [package_name]` command.

My CMake file currently looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22) 

project(untitled)  

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)  
find_package(Eigen3 CONFIG REQUIRED) 
find_package(nlohmann_json CONFIG REQUIRED) 
find_package(FunctionalPlus CONFIG REQUIRED) 
find_package(frugally-deep CONFIG REQUIRED) 

add_executable(untitled main.cpp)
```

I added the directories of the packages to the CMake arguments:

```
-DEigen3_DIR=C:\vcpkg\packages\eigen3_x86-windows\share\eigen3
```

```
-Dnlohmann_json_DIR=C:\vcpkg\packages\nlohmann-json_x86-windows\share\nlohmann_json
```

```
-DFunctionalPlus_DIR=C:\vcpkg\packages\fplus_x86-windows\share\FunctionalPlus
```

```
-Dfrugally-deep_DIR=C:\vcpkg\packages\frugally-deep_x86-windows\share\frugally-deep
```

CMake was able to find the packages for *Eigen3*, *nlohmannjson and FunctionalPlus*. But when I try to add the *frugally-deep* package I get the following error message:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:9 (find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package "frugally-deep" that is
  compatible with requested version "".

  The following configuration files were considered but not accepted:

    C:/vcpkg/packages/frugally-deep_x86-windows/share/frugally-deep/frugally-deepConfig.cmake, version: 0.15.19 (32bit)
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Any reason for not using the toolchain file? [https://vcpkg.io/en/docs/users/buildsystems/cmake-integration.html](https://vcpkg.io/en/docs/users/buildsystems/cmake-integration.html)

Comment: The config may be formed incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

Wild guess: You configured CMake to use x64 instead of x86. As such you cannot use the x86-windows triplet. Also you shouldn't use the `packages` folder. That folder is just a staging area for vcpkg. Consider using `vcpkg.cmake` using a manifest (vcpkg.json) to avoid such problems in the future.